# How to access the element in a multidimensional array after initializing

Tags: php

I have an array

```
$array = [ [1,2], [3,4] ];
```

I initialize :

```
 $array[0][1] = array();
 $array[0][0] = array();

 print_r($array[0][1] =  [ 2 => $array[0][0] ]);
```

the output is:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

But when I try,  `print_r($array[0][1] = [$array[0][0] => $array[0][0] ]);`
It will not output as the previous one..what happened?

Comment: What would you *expect* the output of this nonsensical code to be?

Comment: your array is $array, so $data is from where?

Comment: I want the output to be Array( [2] => Array ( [4] => {} ) )

Comment: Why would `$array[0][0]` be `4`?

Answer (score 1):

**In php, an assignation return the assigned value.**

**First**

```
$data[0][1] = [ 2 => $data[0][0] ])
```

will return

```
array (
    2 => array ()
)
```

** Second **

```
$data[0][1] = [ $array[0][0] => $data[0][0] ]
```

will return

```
array (
    array () => array ()
)
```

In PHP, you can only use ints and strings as a key. This isn't compliant and is an error.